# Wait for function to end VB

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio, office-interop

I'm starting a ne project, in VB. And I have a problem. So maybe I don't understand the logic - can you explain it to me?

In my function `Feuil1_BeforeDoubleClick` i would like to wait for `Button1_Click`to end. 
But i don't know how to achieve this.

Here's the relevant code:

My `Sheet1` :

```
 Imports System.Threading.Tasks
 Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Feuil1

Friend actionsPane1 As New ActionsPaneControl1
Public list As String


Public Sub Feuil1_BeforeDoubleClick(Target As Range, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles Me.BeforeDoubleClick
    If Target.Column <> 1 Then
        If Target.Row = 16 Then
            Globals.ThisWorkbook.ActionsPane.Controls.Add(actionsPane1)
            Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.DisplayDocumentActionTaskPane = True
            'marche pas  SendKeys.Send("{ESC}")
            '
            'wait here for the end of Button1_click

            Target.Value = list
            list = ""
        End If
    End If
    MsgBox("doubleclick end")

End Sub


End Class
```

And there is my `actionpane1` :

```
Public Class ActionsPaneControl1


Friend Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim itemChecked As Object
    Const barre As String = " / "
    For Each itemChecked In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems

        Globals.Feuil1.list = Globals.Feuil1.list + itemChecked.ToString() + barre
    Next


    ' Boucle pour reset la list
    For i = 0 To (CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1)

        CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, False)
    Next

    Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.DisplayDocumentActionTaskPane = False




End Sub



End Class
```

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: Someone does a double click somewhere. Inside the double click handler you want to stop what you are doing at some point until a button is clicked? And once that happened you want to do more things in the double click handler? I have trouble understand why you wouldn't just do the second part in the double click handler in the button handler instead.

Comment: I'm with @Nitram, can you explain why you want to intervene in between the first click and the second? You can't wait on another event inside of an event handler. There's no way to know if the other event is actually executing

Comment: Hello Everybody. As I said maybe i don't understand something.
I explain what I want to perform.
When the user double click a cell, a action pane appear with a chekedlistbox, the user check items and then click the button of the action pane to confirm.
Then the items appears as a string in the cell double clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i think about the problem, and it seems I didn't understand my function doubleclick, was not working after the double click but before ! that was my mistake.

So i change my function to detect, the change of selection in my sheet.
Then i call my action pane.
And work with the event of the button of the action pane.

There is the entire code ( maybe because i don't explain me correctly)

my `Sheet1.vb` :

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Feuil1

 Friend actionsPane1 As New ActionsPaneControl1
 Public list As String
 Public cell As Range

 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range) Handles Me.SelectionChange
    If Target.Column <> 1 Then
        If Target.Row = 16 Then
            Globals.ThisWorkbook.ActionsPane.Controls.Add(actionsPane1)
            Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.DisplayDocumentActionTaskPane = True

            cell = Target
        End If
    End If



 End Sub
End Class
```

and my `actionpanecontrol1.vb` :

```
Public Class ActionsPaneControl1

 Friend Button1Click = False

 Friend Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim itemChecked As Object
    Const barre As String = " / "
    For Each itemChecked In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems

        Globals.Feuil1.list = Globals.Feuil1.list + itemChecked.ToString() + barre
    Next


    ' Boucle pour reset la list
    For i = 0 To (CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1)

        CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, False)
    Next

    Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.DisplayDocumentActionTaskPane = False

    Button1Click = True

    Globals.Feuil1.cell.Value = Globals.Feuil1.list


    Globals.Feuil1.list = ""

 End Sub

End Class
```

Thanks a lot for all your reply

Answer (score 1):

Example taken from https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/139395/how-to-check-if-a-button-was-clicked . Credit is given.
Basicly declare a variable at form level and then set it to true whenever the button is clicked. Reset it when appropriate

```
    Dim bBtnClicked As Boolean = False
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If bBtnClicked = True Then
            MessageBox.Show("This button is clicked already ....")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("This button is clicked First time ....")
        End If
        bBtnClicked = True
    End Sub
```

Alternatively whatever it is that you want to happen after the button is clicked, just put that code in the handler for the button-click event.

Comment: This does not address the question.  Two single clicks is different from a double click.

Comment: Where on earth the OP wanted to wait for a double click? The name of the sub contains the literal "DoubleClick", but that has nothing to do with waiting a double click event. In fact the OP writes: "i would like to wait for Button1_Click to end"

Comment: I disagree with the downvote, It does seem as if OP wants what this answer suggests. A boolean with a check inside BeforeDoubleClick would solve the problem.